# Нахождение прообраза sha1 И md5

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, хеширование

Известны два хешкода одной и той же строки фиксированной длинны полученный sha1 и md5, будет ли насколько нибудь ЛЕГЧЕ найти эту строку зная ДВА хеша, нежели только любой один из них? Может и алгоритм есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно легче.

Дело в том, что конкретному хэшу соответствует много строк, из которых вычисляется именно он.

Поскольку md5 и sha1 независимы, то вероятность угадать нужную строку (производящую заданные md5 и sha1) повышается.

Answer (score 5):

Ну легче то не будет - в смысле производительности/времени. Проще будет в плане уверенности в точности найденного решения.

Обращение хэша некорректная задача, поскольку несколько строк (множество строк) могут иметь одинаковый хэш. Проще будет в том плане что найденная строка от одного хэша может быть проверена на втором хэше и если значения совпадут, то вероятность корректности решения повысится на порядки

Comment: Отлично сформулировано.

Answer (score 1):

Нет нельзя. Они совершенно некоррелируемы.

Единственное можно предполать, перебирать и сравнивать. Любой хэш подвержен атаке, базирующейся на проблеме дня рождения и коллизиям. А для вашего случая вероятность нахождения двух одинаковых хэшей, полагаю, будет несколько выше.

Comment: > Любой хэш пддвержен атаке

    eb575aefb564549d4cbeeaa182289b68b06b6d06

З.Ы. Холивар не развожу)

Comment: Вы правы, но с точки зрения теории это возможно. но никто не говорил что просто

Comment: По моим скромным подсчетам даже с вашим хэшем с вероятностью в 0.99% можно найти коллизию перебав всего 2.5*10^24 вариантов

Comment: @Dex вероятность не отрицаю, я на подборах не специализируюсь) Очень хотелось бы увидеть что я там нашифровал) Точно конечно сам уже не помню, но **123** есть точно)

Comment: согласитесь, для проверки этой теории мне понадобится очень много ресурсов... Тем более что данный перебор позволит лишь найти коллизию, т.е. Это может быть и не ваша последовательнось... Но этого, например, достаточно чтобы взломать аккаунт, если последовательность это ваш пароль

Comment: К **123** Привинчена *соль* состоящая примерно из `&_\90wtfнах` (точно не помню что я там липил) и зашифровано в sha1();

Comment: Интересно, почему если задан вопрос о хэш функциях, то обсуждение сводится к взлому паролей ?

Comment: Каимся =)))

Comment: @avp ты прав +1

Comment: @avp, @Shrek, я сомневаюсь, что контингент начинающих программеров смогут вам ответить где применяется хеширование, максимум ответят что в паролях, а про хеширование ради целостности данных, ради ускорения доступа и пр. даже не вспомнят, если вообще знают.

Answer (score 0):

> [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)
> -Интересно, почему если задан вопрос о хэш функциях, то обсуждение сводится к
> взлому паролей ?

Ответ: есть такой электронный ключ DS1961S(электронный кошелёк)  в нем зашит пароль 64бита и считать его нельзя(банк знает этот пароль, так как он его и записал). Предположим банку надо проверить это тот кошелек или подделка.Тогда с сервера банка приходит блок случайного числа тоже 64 бита. Ключ DS1961S берет это число присоединяет свой пароль и пропускает через SHA-1 хеш функцию и отсылает результат в банк. Одновременно сервер банка берет посланное ранее случайное чило и извесный ему пароль который был записан в ключе и также пропускает через SHA-1 хеш функцию. Далее сервер банка сравнивает свой результат с результатом полученным от ключа. Если результаты совпали то в ключе записан правильный пароль и можно производить дальнейшие банковские операции. В следующий раз сервер банка будет посылать другое  случейное число. Можно перехватить это случайное число а также результат SHA-1 хеш функции соответствующее этому числу, а также много таких пар. Поэтому теоретически тупо подставляя перебирая свой пароль и подсоединяя его к перехваченому случайному числу пропуская через функцию SHA-1 до тех пор пока не получится  результат соответсвенный перехваченому. Далее полученый пароль проверяется на другой паре. Ес ли на другой паре произошло не совпадение то это колизия (пароль не правильный) нужно искать другой пароль. Так вот если найти пароль то можно зделать подделку этого кошелька.

Comment: Вы просто рассказали общую схему, известную еще со времен D-H. Но при чем здесь обсуждение хэш-функций и сведение обсуждения к взлому паролей?

А безопасно ли хранилище ключей у банка?